# Is there a way to change how KDE Connect or Gnome DE handles notifications?

Tags: gnome, kde, notification

Ubuntu 16.04 with Gnome DE

I utilize KDE Connect to send text messages and other notifications to my computer. This program allows me to answer text messages straight from the notification, but only when the notification initially appears on screen.

- If I mouse over it, I can click 'Reply' and send a text straight from the screen.
- If I move the mouse on it then off without clicking (or simply don't get to the notification pop-up in time), the notification will disappear from the screen and go to the notification area.

The problem is that once it goes to the notification area, it is no longer possible to bring up the 'Reply' option on the notification. Clicking anywhere on the notifications from KDE Connect, even when holding down Alt, results in the notification being erased. Is there a way to preserve or access the notification's actions? Is it no longer possible to interact with a notification once it goes to Gnome's notification area?